# Chrome Extension : Modify DOM before loading

Tags: dom, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, loading

My Chrome Extension should modify a DOM element before the DOM is fully constructed, and in the best scenario, right after this DOM element is constructed.

For example, if I have a  in my document, I want to wait until it is constructed, then directly modify it, before the rest of the DOM is constructed.

But I only managed to access the DOM before the  element is constructed and after the entire DOM is constructed.

So how do I listen to the construction of a special element ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [document.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) with the [DOMNodeInserted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference) event. The nodes will be constructed and you will have a chance to modify them before they are inserted into the DOM. Something like the following should work.

```
function nodeInsertedCallback(event) {
  console.log(event);
};
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', nodeInsertedCallback);
```

Comment: You could also include jQuery and use $(function(){}) to be run after the DOM has been created, before the page has loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This event is triggered before the DOM is fully constructed, but it doesn't allow me to modify the DOM content before it is shown. It only triggers for element dynamically added by scripts.

Comment: The DOMNodeInserted event is deprecated. Use [Mutation Observers][1] instead.


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: When I test this DOMContentLoaded gets called before the event-handler for DOMNodeInserted