# How can I block and replace a remote css file in browser?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Let's say there's a stylesheet at https://example.com/x.css. How do I replace that seamlessly on every page load with https://example.com/y.css?

I can use uBlock to block x from loading, but I'm struggling to figure out how to get y to load in its place.

Comment: You could listen for the nodes as they are built with a node listener (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778637/chrome-extension-modify-dom-before-loading), and then as soon as you see the style sheet you want to modify load you can replace it with the one you want.